# Check if json request return anything

Tags: javascript, json

i want to check if a GET requests return anything, i've tried this code

```
 var url = "link";
    $.getJSON(url,function(json){
        if ( json.length == 0 ) {
            console.log("NO DATA!")
        }
    });
```

but it doesnt seem to work. any suggestions?

Comment: Open chrome, press F12 to open the developer's console. Go to the network page and look for the request. Check it's status code. If it is 200 that means your ajax is working. In that case, check the tab "response" (while detailing this request) verify your JSON response and post it here.

Comment: What JSON are you putting in? What result do you expect to get?

Comment: this:{
  "status": "OK",
  "droplets": [
    {
      "id": 100823,
      "name": "test222",
      "image_id": 420,
      "size_id":33,
      "region_id": 1,
      "backups_active": false,
      "ip_address": "127.0.0.1",
      "private_ip_address": null,
      "locked": false,
      "status": "active",
      "created_at": "2013-01-01T09:30:00Z"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: that means it was a success, status [200] OK

Comment: @MeletisFlevarakis — It doesn't have a length property, so what result would you expect that to give?

Comment: i think you want json.droplets.length...

Comment: i made a simple request to check if it does create a request and im getting this error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load api.digitalocean.com/v1/droplets/…;. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '127.0.0.1:61896'; is therefore not allowed access. –

Comment: That simply means that the server doesn't allow Ajax requests from third party domains. You either have use a server side proxy to connect to the server or find out whether the server supports JSONP. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy.

Comment: When you get an error message you don't understand, [search for it](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=No+%27Access-Control-Allow-Origin%27+header+is+present+on+the+requested+resource&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=GKluU4GgO4-DjwfbkYGQCw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a console.log() before the if().

```
var url = "link";
  $.getJSON(url,function(json) {
      console.log("Success received...")
      if ( json.length == 0 ) {
        console.log("NO DATA!")
      }
    });
```

The full reference is here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

And you could also use the .done() capability:

```
  $.getJSON(url)
    .done(function(json) {
        console.log("Success received...")
        if ( json.length == 0 ) {
          console.log("NO DATA!")
        }
      });
```

It could be that somehow you json object is not empty.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.digitalocean.com/v1/droplets/?client_id=234756387456&api_key=5543515. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:61896' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: I'm using digitalocean too, but I have my own Apache and the URI is just something in link with my company and it works just fine... It very much depends on your backend server and any intermediates if any (proxies).

Comment: im using desktopphp with chromium platform. maybe thats the problem. i will try it on nightrain

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want as your question is unclear to me:

if you're not sure if it will or won't return data, just add a condition for each - you're also missing a semicolon, though I don't think that's the issue.

`var url = "link";
    $.getJSON(url,function(json){
        if ( json.length == 0 ) {
            console.log("NO DATA!");
        }
        else {
            console.log("DATA RETURNED!");
        }
    });`